# Vimeo Authorization Required

Tags: django, vimeo

I'm trying to use python-vimeo (https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.py) for uploading videos to Vimeo.

Authorization is done by django-allauth. I receive from it token and token_secret.

But python-vimeo requires authentication code.

How can i get correct authentication code? Because when i send those parameters to

```
VimeoClient(access_token=token,
            client_id='',
            client_secret='')
```

i get an error

HTTPError: HTTP 401: Authorization Required

Does anyone have suggestions where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For authenticating with Vimeo it is recommended you use OAuth 2. Included in the official python-vimeo library is a script for generating an access token (https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.py/blob/master/scripts/authorize.py).

It is highly recommended you use the official python-vimeo library for authentication since the django-allauth maybe not be performing OAuth authentication properly with Vimeo.